# UILabel Fit Text Perfectly

Tags: ios5

I have a UILabel that needs to be set to multiple lines of text. I have set the noOfLines property to 0 and I have the following code:

```
self.aboutLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    self.aboutLabel.text = self.selectedVegetableCategory.about;
[self.aboutLabel sizeToFit];
```

The above code does make the text span multiple lines but still some of the text is missing. I am using CoreData to retrieve the text from db and the fields are varchar but they do not have any limit on it (I have not placed any limit on the number of characters). Does, varchar by default has a limit of number of characters?

UPDATE 1: I just checked again and this is definitely the UILabel issue since CoreData returns the complete text without truncation.

UPDATE 2: The original problem still exists and now there is a new problem. I put a new label just below the original label and now the new label does not move down when the original label expands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the frame of the label before & after the call to `sizeToFit`?

I think that you'll have to provide it a specific frame if you want it to word wrap properly.

Comment: Before SizeToFit: width = 280, height = 44 [After SizeToFit width=279 height=100]

Comment: sizeToFit did work for me in a test app.  I set `numberOfLines` to 0, `lineBreakMode` to Word Wrap and gave it a long string.  There's something else wrong if this isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working! I think the Autoresizing thing was messing it up! Thanks!